Name of ID attribute
Can I use name of properties as ID attribute, for instance #color, #background-color and so on?
Normally I don't use function/property name as variables, attributes, but I wrote one quiz(test) and it is possible to use it.

It is ok there is no problem in doing that keeping in mind id must be unique. For more info visit this link
